# Horror movie with group of young people killed inside a haunted house, girl possessed at the end

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I am trying to find a kind of horror movie with a group of young people in a house, getting stuck there for the night I believe. They start getting killed by objects from the house, and it seems to be possessed by some entity which I don't remember about.

The scene that mostly comes to mind is of a plump girl with short and red hair, who is killed in the kitchen, I guess a knife comes flying after her and cuts her stomach, showing her entrails. I remember her on the ground trying to put them back onto her belly before dying.

By the end of the movie, only a girl with long and black hair, named Kira/Kyra (I think), survived, but it was later discovered that she inherited the entity's power, as she shows when looking at a mirror.

I believe that there is another scene involving a guy being impaled by a horn of a deer head which was hanging on the walls.

My memory must have messed up some of the facts. I think this movie was from between 2004 and 2009. Definitely not more recent than this. I saw it on TV, it might have been a low budget movie that never got much spotlight.

I searched for the character's name on IMDb with no success, and the movie is NOT **See no Evil**.

Comment: The modern "Evil Dead" remake?

Comment: Nope. The one I'm looking for was certainly older than this one. Plus, the stories don't match. I checked all Evil Dead versions and a few direct look-alikes, but couldn't find it. T.T

Comment: On a side note, I was quite surprised to see how many "Kyra" characters I found just on horror movies.

Comment: It has some similarities with the movie "The Haunting (1999)" but it is not that obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, found it finally. The movie is **[Kolobos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolobos)**.

> The film begins with a couple coming across a severely wounded girl that can only utter the word "kolobos". The film then cuts to a few days prior where the same girl, **an artist named Kyra (Amy Weber)**, has agreed to take part in an experimental film.
>
> Her artwork, which are inspired by **a creepy faceless entity**, disturb her new housemates.
>
> **Eventually all but Kyra die** and she is then shown cutting herself with a blade she finds in her bathroom.

And all the rest you mentioned are in the movie as well. Release date is 1999 though.

Comment: This really seems like it. I am going to watch videos to confirm and will return shortly.

Comment: You hit the spot, my friend. Well done. Recognized it as soon as I saw the red haired girl scene. Now I can watch the full movie again. I'm sorry to have mixed up the date, it really seemed more recent when I watched it (might have been brighter on the channel I saw it, idk). That must've been a hell of a search. Well, you earned it. Thank you very much, ermanen.

Comment: Funny that it was actually a girl impaled by the deer horns, not a guy as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be "[Flesh For The Beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesh_for_the_Beast)" ? I did not watch the movie but some parts fit:

- Release year: 2003
- Group of young people
- Locked in a mansion
- Mansion is haunted by an amulet
- Only survivor is a woman who has the power

> The survivor, **Erin**, is then revealed to have been a succubus all along. She had been the warlock's favorite and somehow had lost her memories and gained the ability to leave the mansion. Erin then rejoins the other succubi in the mansion.