# Please identify this horror movie about a girl who was used to trap actors in a house

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, mystery

I watched it about 11 years ago starts with an audition for actors to go into a house to act a reality horror movie only for them to be trapped in a real horror house.

The horror starts with one guy going to the kitchen and getting split into two by a disk coming out of the floor once he opens the fridge door. Later on another guy dies by being impaled into a deer's antler and another's head smashed into a bathroom sink.

The twist at the end is that the girl who survives is actually being used by the monster killing all the people and she had no recollection of it.

She goes back to her normal life, she is a depressed self cutter until the monster asks her to put another ad in the newspaper for more auditions.

I may have misremembered some details but I really need to know the name of the movie.

Comment: This sounds vaguely similar to Saw 2 in a few ways, but it's different enough that I won't put it as the answer.  I'm eager to hear what the title is, it sounds interesting.  Was this film English language?  American accents?

Comment: Yeah it was American to the best of my recollection,

Comment: By the description, I'm pretty sure it is Kolobos, as @sixteenshells pointed out. I was actually looking for this same movie a while ago: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/horror-movie-with-group-of-young-people-killed-inside-a-haunted-house-girl-poss

Answer (score 4):

Is it [Reality Horror Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_Horror_Night)

> The cast enters a mansion to compete on a new reality show for $1
>   million but with an unexpected twist. Mysteriously, a cast member
>   disappears but without a formal elimination ceremony. When more and
>   more castmates start disappearing in this fashion it is up to the
>   remaining cast to discover how this game is really played.

Comment: Does it contain the scenes mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 3):

This is 1999's [Kolobos](http://www.hudsonlee.com/kolobos/). The circular saw and antler deaths are both female victims. From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolobos):

> [A]n artist named Kyra (Amy Weber), has agreed to take part in an experimental film. The film will have several different people living together for three months while the cameras record their interactions. Her artwork, which are inspired by a creepy faceless entity, disturb her new housemates. The group gets along well until night time, when a series of deadly traps pick them off one by one.

Here's the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0V9M5i3Lrs) [Warning: Gory].

Comment: Seems accurate. Added a bit more details & +1.